# Finding a recursive formula for a string of the letters $A,B,C$ such that $AB, BC$ does not appear in

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> Find a recursive formula for a string of the letters $A,B,C$ such that $AB, BC$ does not appear in.

$a_n=\begin {cases}A\text{____}a_{n-1}\\ 
B\text{____}a_{n-1}\\
C\text{____}a_{n-1}\\
-BC\text{____}a_{n-2}\\
-AB\text{____}a_{n-2}\\
-ABC\text{____}a_{n-3} \end{cases}$

So the sequence is $a_n=3a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}$ and the starting conditions are trivial.

But I'm not sure about the $ABC$ part isn't it a double count since I already have the $AB, BC$?

Comment: There's a nice generalization of this problem. The Goulden-Jackson cluster method effectively produces a generating function to count the number of stings that avoid any finite collection of words. See Doron Zeilbergers's http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/gj.html for a paper and programs.

Comment: Why not just use $ACBACBACBACBACB . . .$?

Comment: What about $CBACBACBA$? @NoahSchweber and there are infinitely more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update*: see below for a simpler derivation

Let $x_n$ be $n-$length allowed sequences, $a_n$ be the sequences ending on $A$, $b_n$ the sequences ending on $B$...

Then $$a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n +c_n \tag{1}$$   $$b_{n+1}=b_n +c_n\tag{2}$$ $$c_{n+1}=a_n +c_n\tag{3}$$

Replacing $(2)$ into $(1)$ we get rid of $b_n$:

$$ a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1} +a_n -c_{n+1}=0 \tag{4}$$

Together with $(3)$ this gives $$c_n = a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1} \tag{5}$$

Replacing this again in $(4)$ we get rid of $c_n$:

$$a_{n+3}=3a_{n+2}-2 a_{n+1}+a_n$$

Now, because $x_n=a_n+b_n+c_n=a_{n+1}$ this implies

$$ x_{n+1}=3 x_{n}-2x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$$

Starting with $x_0=1$, $x_1=3$, $x_2=7$, this gives the sequence $1,3,7,16,37,86, 200 \cdots$

---

*Update*: a simpler derivation:

Let $x_n$ be the valid sequences of length $n$. Then $x_{n} = 3 x_{n-1} - y_{n}$ where $y_{n}$ are invalid sequences of length $n$, which are valid up to $n-1$. These correspond to such sequences ending on $AB$ (this count is $x_{n-2}$) plus such sequences ending on $BC$ (this count is $x_{n-2}-x_{n-3}$ -  the last term accounts for the ending $ABC$ subsequence)

Then, $$x_n = 3 x_{n-1} - (x_{n-2} +x_{n-2} -x_{n-3})=3 x_{n-1} - 2 x_{n-2} +x_{n-3}$$

Comment: Why use different sequences for each letter?

Comment: Is there an explanation other the algebraic one to why the last term is a plus?

Comment: The restrictions are different for each letter. Indeed all sequences $a_n$ $b_n$ and $c_n$ are different.

Comment: But can't they be expressed with $x$ from the start?

Comment: @leonbloy  I think you need to add the initial condition that x(2) = 7 since we need 3 terms to get us started.  Right?

Comment: @kuhaku : I don't know how you'd write the recursion not starting with the discrimimination in $a, b,c$ (perhaps it's possible, I don't know). In any case, equations $1-3$ , which express the restrictions, cannot be written directly in terms of $x_n$, as far as I can see.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer : Yes, you are right; the recursion works using $x_{-1}=0$ but that would be difficult to justify (actually, even using the value $x_0=1$ needs some justification, as $x_n=a_n+b_n+c_n$ is false for $n=0$...)

Comment: @kuhaku : I've updated the answer with a much simpler derivation, in the spirit of the inclusion-exclusion counting you suspected

Answer (score 1):

I think the last term in your recurrence should be PLUS a(n-3).  I solve these problems using systems of generating functions.  This sequence is Sloane's OEIS A095263.  If it helps you to see my Mathematica code then look below.  The functions a[x], b[x], and c[x] are respectively the g.f.'s for valid words starting with A, starting with B, and empty or starting with C. What we want is a[x]+b[x]+c[x].  The method is a bit subtle but it seems very fruitful in terms of economy of thought.

sol = Solve[{a[x] == x a[x] + x c[x], b[x] == x a[x] + x b[x] + x, 
   c[x] == 1 + x a[x] + x b[x] + x c[x]}, {a[x], b[x], c[x]}]

{{a[x] -> -((x - x^2 + x^3)/(-1 + 3 x - 2 x^2 + x^3)), 
  b[x] -> ((-1 + x) x)/(-1 + 3 x - 2 x^2 + x^3), 
  c[x] -> ((-1 + x) (1 - x + x^2))/(-1 + 3 x - 2 x^2 + x^3)}}

Simplify[a[x] + b[x] + c[x] /. sol]

1/(1 - 3 x + 2 x^2 - x^3)

nn = 10; CoefficientList[Series[1/(1 - 3 x + 2 x^2 - x^3), {x, 0, nn}], x]

{1, 3, 7, 16, 37, 86, 200, 465, 1081, 2513, 5842}

Comment: But why is it a plus?

Comment: HI kuhaku, It is plus because plus  is correct.  I wonder if you are trying to make a somewhat difficult problem into something very simple.  Look at the answer by leonbloy.  He used a SYSTEM of recurrences describing valid words that END in A or B or C.  I did the same thing using a SYSTEM of generating functions that describe valid words STARTING with A or B or C.  It looks like you might be trying to oversimplify the problem?

Comment: LOL I can see it's correct, I'm asking because it looks like inclusion exclusion or complement. It's just I wasn't supposed to solve this using a a system of recurrence relations, I haven't seen much of them really.

Comment: @kuhaku  OK, I see now why you are asking.  I do not know if there is some combinatorial argument that we can make about these words  to explain the terms in the  recurrence.  I looked at the sequence on OEIS and none is given.  In my experience with restricted words there usually is not.  If you (or anyone) can make one I would be very interested.  Thanks for your question!

Comment: @kuhaku Yes, the formula looks as if it were possible to prove it from some far simpler counting argument - and might be it is - but I couldn't. You might want to un-accept my answer for a while, just in case someone comes with a simpler deduction.